# Just change float of a radio and label element

Tags: html, css, radio-button, label, css-float

I wanna to change floats, You can see it (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uqCts)

Now the label is in the **right** and radio button is in **left**, I wanna to chage it..
How can i do that?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this sample code:

```
input[type=radio].css-checkbox {
   display:none;
}

input[type=radio].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
  padding-right:17px;
  height:12px; 
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:12px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: right 0;
  color:#9a9a9a;
  vertical-align:middle;
  cursor:pointer;
}
input[type=radio].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
  background-position: right -12px;
}
label.css-label {
  background-image:url(http://upcity.ir/images2/00476056564652779386.png);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

You have to change the `padding-left` for `padding-right` of your `input[type=radio].css-checkbox + label.css-label` and play with the background position.